# Genetic algorithm framework coded in C++

Tags: c++, algorithms

I'm currently working on an optimization problem using binary integer programming and I want to use a meta-heuristic such as Genetic Algorithm. For that, I'm working with a free optimization tool called SCIP and I want to integrate some GA libraries in my project. I'm trying to use the framework OpenBEAGLE which is a bit outdated. I'm having loads of linking errors and for that reason this integration in SCIP is not going so well.

I was wondering if any of you know and/or could advice me any other framework/libraries like OpenBEAGLE which is powerful enough to handle big binary data and which could possibly have a nice interplay with SCIP.

So far I've found:

- GALGO (https://github.com/olmallet81/GALGO-2.0) which looks quite nice but I don't find much documentation about it... and it seems to be not so powerful
- ParadisEO (http://paradiseo.gforge.inria.fr/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) which seems promising but it is template-based in ANSI-C++ (??) AND might be too complex
- Evolving Objects which is currently offline

Thanks in advance.